# React - Firebase handling Auth persistence using a separate auth class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, persistence, google-signin

I am building a react app that uses a simple login feature. I am only using google sign in, and am calling the `signInWithPopop` function to handle that. I have created a separate class to handle all the auth related code. On the navbar of my website I have a login button if the user is not signed in which switches to a profile button when the user has signed in.

This is how I am currently checking if the user is signed in (not working):

```
console.log(authHandler.getUser());
const[loginState, setLogin] = useState(authHandler.getUser()? true : false);
return(
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="nav-options">
        <NavItem name="About"></NavItem>
        <NavItem name="Listings"></NavItem>
        <NavItem name="Dashboard"></NavItem>
        {loginState ? <NavItem name="Profile"><DropDown loginState={setLogin}></DropDown></NavItem> : <NavItem name="Login" click={() => authHandler.signIn(setLogin)}></NavItem>}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

This is what I have for my authHandler class:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class Auth{
    constructor(){
        var firebaseConfig = {
            ...
        };
        !firebase.apps.length? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.app();
        firebase.analytics();
        this.provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    }

    signIn(state){
        firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION).then(() => {
            return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(this.provider).then((result) => {
                console.log("signed in " + result.user.uid);
                this.user = result.user
                state(true);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
        })
    }

    getUser(){
        return firebase.auth().currentUser;
    }

    logout(state){
        //TODO: logout of firebase
        state(false);
    }
}
```

I have tried adding session and local persistence on firebase, but when I refresh the page, the user is signed out. What would be the proper way of maintaining persistence, in a separate class like this? I am trying to build this app with best practices in mind so that the code will be split up properly, and security is maintained.

Thanks!

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onauthstatechanged You need to watch the "log state" and apply it in any state of your app. When you refresh, firebase verify if any older connexion exists before it updates `firebase.auth().currentUser` value.

Comment: Can this be implemented in a separate class, and have changes reflected elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use an [auth state observer](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data) to get a callback whenever the user's sign in state changes.  When a page first loads, the user is always immediately considered to be signed out.  The callback will be invoked some time soon after the user's token has been loaded from persistence and verified.  Use this state callback to determine what to render.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    var uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```

You might want to show a loading screen until the first callback tells you for sure if the user was previously signed in or is definitely signed out.

I suggest [reading this for more information](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0).

Comment: How would I implement this as a separate class? Would I pass a hook to the auth classes constructor, and change the state when user returns not null? This would leave it in an infinite loading loop if the user never signed in. Do you have any suggestions on implementing the listener?

Comment: I suggest making an attempt at a solution, then ask a new question with the code that isn't working the way you expect.  There are any number of ways to implement this, depending on your chosen app architecture.  The bottom line is that you need this listener somewhere in your app to detect changes and react accordingly.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much. I just made a new function called getCurrentStatus and added the listener there. It seems to be working now. Just a quick question, does the listener automatically kill itself, or is there something that I should do?

Comment: No, you have to write code to remove the listener if you no longer want it active on a page.  Use the API documentation to learn about that.

Answer (score 0):

The way I implemented the auth state in react :

Auth.provider.tsx

```
import React, {
  FC,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import { User, auth } from 'firebase/app';

interface AuthContext {
  user: User | null;
  loading: boolean;
}

const defaultAuthContext = { user: null, loading: false };

const AuthUserContext = createContext<AuthContext>({ ...defaultAuthContext });

export const AuthUserProvider: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [authContext, setAuthContext] = useState<AuthContext>({
    user: null,
    loading: true,
  });

  useEffect(
    () =>
      auth().onAuthStateChanged((authUser) =>
        setAuthContext({ user: authUser, loading: false }),
      ),
    [],
  );

  return (
    <AuthUserContext.Provider value={authContext}>
      {children}
    </AuthUserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useAuthUser = () => useContext(AuthUserContext);
```

App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  return <AuthUserProvider>
    // anything
  </AuthUserProvider>;
}
```

anycomponent.tsx

```
const { user, loading } = useAuthUser();

return loading ? <Loader /> : !user ? <NotLogged /> : <Logged />;
```

You could implement the observer in your class but everytime you'll need your user you should implement an useEffect watching the user. Making it global in a provider make it easier to use.

There are many other way but I think this one is the easiest to use.